# Basic test of checkbox submit button fails?

Tags: php, checkbox, submit

Here are the two pages, the 1st has a checkbox and submit button, the 2nd is php code to examine whether the checkbox was checked. But instead of getting a yes or a no answer I get absolutely nothing, just a blank page.

1st page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<body>

      <form name="input" action="submit.html" method="GET">
    cb1<input type="checkbox" name="cb1" value="cb1">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
     </form>
</body>
</html>
```

2nd page:

```
<?php
if isset($_GET['cb1']) {
    echo 'Checkbox set';
}
else
{
    echo 'Checkbox is not set';
}
?>
```

Comment: do you want to use radio button instead of checkbox for yes/no?

Answer (score 2):

There is a mistake in your PHP-Code - you should enable "error_reporting" and "display_errors"!

The if Statement should be like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['cb1'])) {
```

Edit: Also the Submit-Page should be an PHP-File

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be submitting to an html page ("submit.html"). Unless you do some url rewritting, that should be a php page.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this `<form name="input" action="submit.html" method="GET">`. When you click submit button, then all the data will be send to `submit.html`. It's impossible to run php script with `html` extension.

Answer (score 0):

Create the second file as a php file, instead of creating it as .html, create it as submit.php. Then it will work